# How can I display a random set of slides with the Twitter Bootstrap carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

How can I create an array of slides and then only display a certain number of them randomly?

For example, if I set up an array like this:

```
var slides = [];
slides[0] = '<div class="item"><img alt="" src="/Slides/gallery.jpg"></div>';
slides[1] = '<div class="item"><img alt="" src="/Slides/item1.jpg"></div>';
slides[2] = '<div class="item"><img alt="" src="/Slides/forums.jpg"></div>';
slides[3] = '<div class="item"><img alt="" src="/Slides/featured.jpg"></div>';
slides[4] = '<div class="item"><img alt="" src="/Slides/sale.jpg"></div>';
slides[5] = '<div class="item"><img alt="" src="/Slides/discount.jpg"></div>';
slides[6] = '<div class="item"><img alt="" src="/Slides/gallery.jpg"></div>';
slides[7] = '<div class="item"><img alt="" src="/Slides/a.jpg"></div>';
slides[8] = '<div class="item"><img alt="" src="/Slides/b.jpg"></div>';
slides[9] = '<div class="item"><img alt="" src="/Slides/c.jpg"></div>';
slides[10] = '<div class="item"><img alt="" src="/Slides/d.jpg"></div>';
```

How can I choose 5 of the 10 at random and then output it into the Twitter Bootstrap carousel?

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
    [Items go here, first one needs to get the class 'active']
</div>
```

Comment: I would fill the "Items go here" with server-side code; forget the JS array. For example, in PHP, you could use [array_rand](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to get a random subset. Otherwise... if you really want to use JS, then pick a few elements at random and append them to your div. You may have to initialize the carousal afterwords using the API.

Comment: I was going to post an answer for you but as it turns out, it's much harder to shuffle an array properly with Javascript (without a plugin) than it is in PHP etc as @Mark mentions above. Now the other reason you should be doing this on the server side is that you'll be saving load time/resources by not bringing back all the possibilities before they are randomly selected, and you place slides with JS, if the client has Javascript disabled they see nothing. At least if you place them with HTML & PHP (etc) you will see them.

Comment: In addition to what the others have said, I'd only put the filename in your array, not a big gob of HTML that's identical for each item. Loop through them to render the HTML in the page, or do it server-side.

Comment: The site isn't PHP-driven though. Also, the HTML for the slides will be different (text, etc.), but I just wanted to show a basic example. Any recommendations on how to do this with JavaScript, jQuery, or a specific plugin?

Comment: Surely you're using *some* server-side language? It doesn't have to be PHP. I don't have any code for you, there's really not much to it. Write a standard for loop, and append each slide. `$('#myCarousel').append(slides[i])`. Then initialize it, `$('#myCarousel').carousel()`. Once you've got that working, work on picking a random subset of elements.